# Let $G$ be a subgroup of the multiplicative group $\mathbb{C}^*$. such that $g \in G$ where $|g| = 1$

Tags: metric-spaces, compactness, topological-groups

> Let $G$ be a subgroup of the multiplicative group $\mathbb{C}^*$. such that $g \in G$ where $|g| = 1$ then is the set bounded and closed subset of $\mathbb{C}$? If so can we use the heine-borel theorem in this case to show that it is compact (As $\mathbb{C} \cong \mathbb{R}^2$)

I tried to show that any subset of $\mathbb{C}$ which is bounded will have $|g| = 1$.

Assume that the set $G$ is bounded and there is a $g \in G$ such that $|g| > 1$ . Let $|g| = 1+\epsilon$ where $\epsilon > 0 $ . Then as $G$ is a subgroup of $G$ then we can conclude that $g^n \in G$ for all $n \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Then $|g|^n = (1+\epsilon)^n$ .

Now we know that $|(a+ib)| = \sqrt{(a^2 + b^2)}$ which defines a norm on $\mathbb{C}$.

We know that in a normed linear space any set is bounded iff $||x|| \le M$ for some $M \in \mathbb{R}$.

Then assume that there exists a $M >0 $ such that $|g| \le M$ for all $g \in G$.

Now we know that by the archimedian property of $\mathbb{R}$ there exists an $N_1 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $N_1 . \epsilon > M$ .

let $|g|^{N_1} = (1+\epsilon)^{N_1} > 1 + N_1.\epsilon > M $ which is a contradiction.

> Is the set $G$ closed? If so can we use the heine-borel theorem to conclude that it is compact?(by assuming $\mathbb{C} \cong \mathbb{R}^2$?)

Comment: just be be clear, $G$ is the set of all complex numbers on the unit circle with multiplication, correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is negative. Take, for instance, $G=\left\{e^{i\theta}\,\middle|\,\theta\in\Bbb Q\right\}$. Then $G$ is not a closed subset of $S^1$, and therefore it is not compact.

Comment: Related topic for OP to look into: the irrational rotation algebra.

Comment: How are we showing that it is not closed - If I take a continuous map $f:G \to \mathbb{R}$ by $f(e^{i\theta} )= \theta$ . Then $\mathbb{Q}$ is not closed in $\mathbb{R}$? Also you claimed that it is not compact - are we using the heine borel theorem?

Comment: You can show it isn't closed by considering a few special points on the unit circle. They won't have a preimage. I suggest playing with Desmos to see if you can tell anything about it, but it turns out that the set José mentioned is actually dense in the unit circle.

Comment: @ThirstForMaths It is not closed because if $(\theta_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ is a sequence of rational numbers such that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\theta_n=\pi$, then each $e^{i\theta_n}$ belongs to $G$, but $\lim_{n\to\infty}e^{i\theta_n}=e^{i\pi}=-1\notin G$.

Comment: @CameronWilliams Sorry if it seems stupid but I don't understand what preimage are we talking about? How do I visualize the picture? It just seems to be closed to me

Comment: Yep that's exactly what I had in mind, José.

Comment: How are you concluding that it is not compact ?

Comment: Since it is not closed, it is not compact.

Comment: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/rzxxcartlj not sure if this link works, but it could help with exploration. Adjust $n$ to watch it "fill" the circle.

Comment: @CameronWilliams so the dots are not filling the circle . Is this the reason why the circle is not closed ?

Comment: @ThirstForMaths, yeah if you notice, some points will never be attained (like $-1$), but they will have points that get arbitrarily close to them.

Comment: So is there a general way in which we can defined the closed sets of $\mathbb{C}$ which forms a subgroup of $\mathbb{C}^*$?